# Making and applying git patch

Tags: git

I don't know much about git patch system, but I needed to make patch. I have my repository, then I commited change and wrote in console: `git format-patch [my commit hash] -o patch`. Then I got my patch. When I made a new project and new repository, I tried to apply this patch using `git am solution.patch` but I got tons of error. Mostly *no such file or directory*. Is there any way to apply patch with making new files? Or how can I check if my patch even works?

Comment: The patch corresponds to the changes made in the commit. If you apply it to an empty repository, only changes creating new files can be applied, modifications to existing files will fail as there are no files to modify.

Comment: And if I have one project and copy of it, one I will leave plain as it is and the second one I will edit (I will make few new files, make some changes to existing etc), and then I will make patch out of my last commit. Should I be able to apply this patch to plain project? I tried to doing this with my current project, but it didn't seem to work. I got this _no such file or directory_ error. Is there any way for making it work?

Comment: Why don't you just clone the existing repository?

Comment: The company that i'm applying asked specifically for patch. Additionaly I need to make sure that patch contains only needed data.

Comment: Well, as you've been told, you can't patch what isn't there.